# Biological Taxonomy Data Model

Tags: language-agnostic, database-design, data-structures, datamodel

Looking for industry/standard data model for biological classification.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_classification)

Comment: Perhaps, is that the standard?

Comment: No, just a bad pun. Move along, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main approach is the GeneOntology (GO) http://www.geneontology.org/. This is one of a series of carefully managed ontologies under the OBO foundation (http://www.obofoundry.org/).

Comment: that looks like what I am looking for. have any direct links to the database model?

Comment: The ontologies can be expressed in OWL-RDF